# How to group rows in data frame while counting occurrences in one column and summing values in other?

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to modify my data frame:

```
  start end duration_time
1     1   2         2.438
2     2   1         3.901
3     1   2        18.037
4     2   3        85.861
5     3   4        83.922
```

and create something like this:

```
  start end duration_time weight
1     1   2        20.475      2
2     2   1         3.901      1
4     2   3        85.861      1
5     3   4        83.922      1
```

So the duplicate start-end combinations will be removed, the weight will raise and duration time will sum

I already have a part working I just can't get the weight to work:

```
library('plyr')

df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "start end duration_time
1     1   2         2.438
2     2   1         3.901
3     1   2        18.037
4     2   3        85.861
5     3   4        83.922")

ddply(df, c("start","end"), summarise, weight=? ,duration_time=sum(duration_time))
```

Comment: what does "weight will raise mean"? is that your count variable?

Comment: all your attempt needed was `ddply(df, .(start, end), summarise, weight=length(duration_time), duration_time=sum(duration_time))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `base R` option is `aggregate`

```
do.call(data.frame, aggregate(duration_time~., df1,
       FUN = function(x) c(duration_time=sum(x), weight = length(x))))
```

Comment: nice one thank you, do you think that this is slower than the data table solution?

Comment: @ayshelina In genera, `aggregate` would be slower but for smaller datasets, this would serve the purpose

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution using data.table :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(duration_time=sum(duration_time), wt = .N) , by  =c("start", "end")]

   start end duration_time wt
1:     1   2        20.475  2
2:     2   1         3.901  1
3:     2   3        85.861  1
4:     3   4        83.922  1
```

---

Trying something using dplyr, tidyr

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 <- df %>% unite(by_var, start,end)
df2 <- cbind(df1 %>% count(by_var), df1 %>% group_by(by_var)%>% 
    summarise( duration_time=sum(duration_time))%>%
    separate(by_var, c("start","end")))[c(3,4,5,2)]

> df2
  start end duration_time n
1     1   2        20.475 2
2     2   1         3.901 1
3     2   3        85.861 1
4     3   4        83.922 1
```

Comment: if youre going to use dplyr, why not just `df %>% group_by(start, end) %>% summarise(weight = n(), duration_time = sum(duration_time))`

Comment: @rawr: That's what I'd go for - put it as an answer for others.